# Отпарсить html из json, закодированного в gzip

Tags: python, scrapy

С сервера приходит вот такой json

```
{'html':    '<li itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" data-id="273096" data-mid="" data-fid="87" data-cid="354" class="product_item-price_buy-b"><meta itemprop="name" content="Венозол крем 50 мл"/><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB"/><div class="search-page--clearfixer clearfix"><div class="leftcol"><div class="img-wrap"><a href="/product273096/product_info.html" title="Венозол крем 50 мл" onclick="owox_product_click(this, '', 'Венозол крем 50 мл', '354', '273096', 'eapt210042', '', … class="presence-list">25<li class="green"></li><li class="green"></li><li class="green"></li><li class="green"></li><li class="green"></li></ul></div></div></div> <div class="delivery"> <div><a href="/delivery.html">Доставка по Москве</a> — сегодня, 21 мая, бесплатно от 1500 руб.</div> <div><a href="/delivery.html?delivery_type=2">Самовывоз</a> — сегодня, 21 мая, бесплатно</div> </div></li>',
'more': 'Показать ещё 25 товаров',
'links':    '<a href="/search_result.html?sort=4a" data-sort="4a" class="bs-title" data-placement="right" title="Сортировать цены по убыванию">по цене</a><a href="/search_result.html?sort=6d" data-sort="6d" class="bs-title current" data-placement="bottom" title="Сортировать популярность по убыванию">по популярности <i class="piluli-59"></i></a>',
'header':   'Найдено 4142 товара',
'debug' {
'manuf_search': false,
'start_price':  false,
'end_price':    false,
'reserv_search':    false,},
'filter':   '<div class="filter-sidebar js-filter-sidebar-wrap"> <a href="#" class="mobile-title js-mobile-title">Фильтр товаров <i class="piluli-51"></i> <i class="piluli-52"></i></a> <div class="filter-for-mobile js-filter-for-mobile"> <div class="unit js-unit-wrap" id="filter_forms"> <a href="#" class="unit-link js-unit-link active">Форма выпуска <i class="piluli-51"></i> <i class="piluli-52"></i></a> <div class="dropdown-unit js-dropdown-unit" style="displ… </div> </div> <div class="btn-wrap"> <a href="#" class="btn-reg" id="filter_submit">Применить</a> <a href="#" class="btn-link" id="filter_kill">Сбросить фильтры</a> </div> </div> </div> <script> $(function(){ $('._show_all_items').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('ul').find('li').show(200); $(this).remove(); }) initUI(); }) </script>',
'l':    2}
```

Заголовки:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
```

Надо получить html.
Код обработки объекта Response (Scrapy):

```
import json

# здесь был код запроса
data = json.loads(response.body)
```

Результат:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can`t decode byte 0xc8 in position 4631: invalid continuation byte
```

Еще пробовал оборачивать response.body в `gzip.decompress()`. Получил ответ, что файл закодирован не `gzip`. Какие есть решения?
UPD: ковертация в json не удается из-за того, что value начинается со знака '<'.

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip` значит что данные будут в этом сжиматься пока идут от сервера на клиент (или наоборот), а вы уже получате расжатые данные

Comment: Попробуйте в loads указать кодировку `cp1251`

Comment: @gil9red, это не помогает. Объект не превращается в json, потому что value начинается с '<'.

Comment: @Elefanobi, уточните вопрос. "С сервера приходит вот такой __json__" противоречит "Объект не превращается в json, потому что value начинается с '<'."

Comment: @MaxU, пришедший с сервера json не превращается в объект модуля json питона.

Comment: Автор, приведите в вопросе полный код, чтобы я мог его у себя запустить и с такой же проблемой столкнуться :)

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - желательно с соответствующим кодом